# How to get that there is no AJAX call is pending to load?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I am writing an automation test program which should test any site.

I want to click some element of document, but before that I want to verify that no any AJAX call is running.

I'll only have document, not any AJAX call URLs or something like that.

Is there any ways so I can verify on document that No AJAX requests are being executed.

How can I do that?

Comment: Modify the native XMLHttpRequest method. Boom, done ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Simple answer: you can't**. HTTP is stateless, the browser can't know if a request has been sent and if we are still waiting for a reply.

The only one who can know, is the application itself, using the application logic. Set a variable when you're waiting for an AJAX reply, add to a list, increase a counter... you can then 'watch' for variables.

I'm afraid I don't know of an elegant way to achieve this. Encapsulating all AJAX calls in a method and using the method instead might work - you can disable the testing code when you go live.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has several [AJAX event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/). If you set `ajaxIsExecuting` to true on `ajaxStart` and set it to false on `ajaxStop`, you should have some idea of whether AJAX is executing or not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need javascript either? So you can use this kind of code;

```
 javascript:void(d=document);if(frames.length){alert('Script doesnt work in frame');}else
    {while((el=d.getElementsByTagName('script')).length
        {el[0].parentNode.removeChild(el[0]);};onerror=function(){};d.close();}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use technique below:

```
var loadingarray=[];

function GetCommand(id, sid) {
    if (loadingarray[id]) {return false;}
    loadingarray[id] =  true;
        getCommandResponse = $.ajax({
//send id to server
         ....
         ....
        });

}

function AjaxFinishedGet(xml, status) {
//retrieve id from server in xml
    loadingarray[id] = false;
    ...
    ...
}
```

and then you can simple check loadingarray has true value. If it has; some of ajax call running with id. If it hasn't you know that there isn't any ajax process on run.